# Testing, code organization, sql schema

Tags: python, postgresql, testing, code-organization

I'm using python and postgresql. For testing purposes I'm used to writing a small abstraction over testing.postgresql in order to support schema loading and populating the database with test data.
I have been exploring various approaches to web crawler architectures lately and even learnt some nosql, however it doesn't cut it for me and it's time to go back to postgresql. What are the possible shortcuts in dealing with database schemas in tests? I'm looking for ways to minimise programming effort in relation to database. I'm not using any ORMs, though. I write my schema in plain ordinary sql. However, these files have to be loaded in order, I usually put them in "sql/schema" directory, and my tests are in "tests" directory, etc. I am looking for ways to remove the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called database migrations.

There are many tools that provide this among them [django migrations](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjGwbTyu73bAhXML8AKHXqfB14QFghDMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.djangoproject.com%2Fen%2F2.0%2Ftopics%2Fmigrations%2F&usg=AOvVaw1RSljT84aRFl2mK2pOGTKl), [SQLAlchemy Migrate](http://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and a very simple that should work for you - [mschematool](https://github.com/aartur/mschematool).

Every such tool is to some degree opinionated and provides a structure for schema management code.

Comment: Not quite. I'm not looking strictly for migrations. I have a a full schema, in vcs. testing.postgresql can use cache, and has a copy_data_from option, but what i'm looking for is "load_all_files_from_dir" and run these functions after initdb.
This mschematool is probably the closest to what I'm after.